# Send ObjectId using jwt.sign error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

I've been trying to send the user object id when a user logs i via the logintoken so that i can access it in my index.html using: but it keeps giving a error: SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

```
    var token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username, email:user.email,
 id = user._id }, secret, { expiresIn: '24h' }); // Logged in: Give user token
```

When this token is assigned to the user, how do i get the user  object id in the index.html? This should follow when i run the following code, right?

```
// Route to get the currently logged in user
    router.post('/me', function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.decoded); // Return the token acquired from middleware
    });
```

Comment: Think about why you're using a semicolon for `username` and `email`, but an equal sign for `id`.

Comment: I'm quite new to this so I'm not really sure, could you point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: `..., id : user._id }`